# How do I use Selenium and Python to click on a button when the text changes to something different?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been testing some new browser automation tools. One of them being Selenium. One thing I am working  on is using Python to open a web page. Go to that web page and look for a certain button. If the button says "Yes Button" do nothing and just refresh the page. If the button changes after a refresh to "No Button" then click on that button. I will post the code below. The only thing I left out is my website address. Any help is really appreciated. Currently my script below does the refresh part but when the button changes to "No Button" it just stops and will not click on the button. I am not sure if my while loop is wrong or my understanding of Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
################import the chrome web driver and define the location###############
PATH = "c:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
###################################################################################

###########open the web page and print the title##############
driver.get("https://mywebsite.com")
print(driver.title)
time.sleep(1)
##############################################################

#Look for search button and wait for it to change to something else. 
while True:
    searchbutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Yes Button")))
    driver.refresh()
else:
    searchbutton = driver.find_element_by_link_text("No Button")
    searchbutton.click()
```

Comment: Give the actual link

Comment: It is just a little test website that I built. I put a button on there and that is it. https://kjustin765.wixsite.com/website

Comment: @jkotts When does it change to a No button? I refreshed the button..it stays the same?

Comment: I have to change it manually.I can change it for you if you like.

Comment: So, you are saying when you change the text label of the button from Yes button to No button it cannot find it?

Comment: I changed it now.

Comment: When the button says yes. The page will refresh and keep looking. While the page is refreshing I will change the button to No. After it refreshes and sees the button has changed to No. I want it to click on the button but it doesn't. It just stops and does nothing.

Comment: Lemme run it and see what is happening.

Comment: No error. The button currently says "Yes Button". The website launches and continuously refreshes. Which is what we want. While the script is running. I changed the button to "No Button" on the WIX site and published it. The website refreshes and sees the button changed from "Yes Button" to "No Button". The script just stops it does not click on the button "No Button". It seems like its not executing the else statement.

Comment: Ok.Try now. I'm off to dinner. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AbrarAhmed See my error below. I am heading off to lunch as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else:
    searchbutton = driver.find_element_by_link_text("No Button")
    searchbutton.click()` It never reaches here because `While is always True
```

The program never reaches this part because it never gets out of `While True`. It should be something like this. Also Excpected Conditions will make the driver wait for the element to appear failing which, it will give a timeout error. So, we do it like this.

```
   while True:
    button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="comp-khm867e6"]/a/span')
   
    if 'Yes' in button1.text:
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(10)
    elif 'No' in button1.text:
        button1.click()
        break
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224731/discussion-on-answer-by-abrar-ahmed-how-do-i-use-selenium-and-python-to-click-on).